# Should I grant base.ReadPermissions to Alfresco Consumer?

Tags: acl, alfresco, cmis, opencmis

- Short story : I'm thinking of granting this Action to all Consumers. Security-wise, how stupid would that be ?
- Long story :

I'd like to use the OpenCmis API to get a User's allowed actions, on a given Alfresco Resource.

This way, I will decide which UI-controls I should Enable or Render. I have created a function that scans the user's allowed actions on that resource and Checks if a given one is among them, e.g  CAN_CHECK_OUT, or  CAN_GET_CONTENT_STREAM.

My function works like that:

```
private static Boolean canUserPerformAction_(Session cmisSession, String cmisObjId, String actionKey){

    try{
        OperationContext operationContext = new OperationContextImpl();
        operationContext.setIncludeAcls(true);
        CmisObject obj = getResourceById(cmisSession, cmisObjId);

        obj = (CmisObject)cmisSession.getObject(obj, operationContext);

        Acl acl = obj.getAcl();
        AllowableActions actions = obj.getAllowableActions();
        Set<Action> allowedActions = actions.getAllowableActions();


        for(Action act :allowedActions){
            if(actionKey.equals( act.name() ) ){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        log.debug("Error accessing Object allowed actions | "+e.toString());
    }
    return false;
}
```

But this method returns false Negatives for Users with Consumer/Read Role. It took me some time to realize that the Action `CAN_GET_ACL` was binded for role `cmis:all` and `base.ReadPermissions`, so a Consumer couldn't fetch the ACLs at all, so my method will create an empty 'allowedActions' Array. Looking at the cmis:mapping I can see that:

```
<cmis:mapping>
          <cmis:key>canGetACL.Object</cmis:key>
          <cmis:permission>cmis:all</cmis:permission>
          <cmis:permission>{http://www.alfresco.org/model/system/1.0}base.ReadPermissions</cmis:permission>
        </cmis:mapping>
```

An obvious solution would be to enable `base.ReadPermissions` to all users on the Company Home. But I'm not sure if this is the best way to deal with that, maybe I'm opening some security holes. Would that be a good solution ?

Or maybe I should find another way to check permissions? Any suggestions?

Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but why do you need the ACLS of an object?

You want to enable/disable actions, so if you can get the Allowable Actions then that's enough.
Why do you even want to see if user/group x has permissions on an object?

If you look at the possible result of the [Allowable Actions CMIS API](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/CMIS_Web_Scripts_Reference#CMIS_Allowable_Actions) then there is all you need to know. Also set in the **operationContext** the [include Actions](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/CMIS_Web_Scripts_Reference#Include_Allowable_Actions) to true)

If you want to know the permissions on an object and what to do other stuff than enable/disable actions then use an admin account to check the permissions and cross-check it with the current user.

Secondly: I don't think it can do harm to enable the permission, but in long-term regarding upgrades etc. I wouldn't change the default permissions. I'd then create a custom permissionGroup which has this permission and apply that on the EVERYONE group at the top level.

Comment: thanx, lots of good points here. However I'm not using the webScripts API you propose, but the Apache chemistry OpenCmis, and I couldn't find another way to get the allowed actions

Comment: Oke, but in the Apache chemistry OpenCMIS you can define if you want the atom binding, json or WebService binding. So I guess you need to dig in a bit more in CMIS in total.